# What kind of electronic component is this?

Tags: transformer, identification, coil, camera, trigger

I am trying to repair the flash of a P900 camera, since it gives a burning smell after being used.

After disassembling the flash unit, I came across this part for which I need some professional eyes in order to identify what kind of component that is.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like a teeny-tiny auto-transformer for generating the high voltage for the flash. Is that the hot shoe it's attached to?

Comment: Looks to me like the trigger coil. Is there a 3rd wire going to it on the underside perhaps ?

Comment: Nikon Coolpix P900 is a nice camera (irrelevant of course).

Comment: thanks for the quick replies. i added another image to the question.

Comment: Nikon Coolpix P900 Camera Pop-Up Flash w/ View Finder Assembly Replacement Part
https://www.ebay.com/itm/Nikon-Coolpix-P900-Camera-Pop-Up-Flash-w-View-Finder-Assembly-Replacement-Part-/372096592208

Comment: there are 2 soldered connections to one side of the component. Another wire is connected to the opposite site of that component and that wire is connected to the "middle" of the flash tube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the trigger transformer that provides high voltage to the trigger plate in the bulb. This ionises the gas inside the tube, making it conductive and thereby initiating the flash.

A more in depth explanation of the operating principle of such a flash circuit can be found [here.](https://www.butlerwinding.com/trigger-transformers-theory/)

Comment: i see, thanks for the fast answer. is dc or ac supplied to the bulb itself?

Comment: @abdussamed17 DC. A charging circuit charges up a capacitor with a high DC voltage which is applied across the bulb, ready to go. A pulse on the trigger plate ionises the gas in the tube allowing the DC voltage to arc trough.